# Discord Bot Presence

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've recently made a Discord bot using discord.js v12 and I haven't been able to set a presence for the bot.

This is the code:

```js
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: '.help' }, status: 'online' });
```

And the error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null`.

Comment: How did you define `client`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=user) class docs here, you can see that the type of the `user` property has type `?ClientUser` with `?` out the front - this means that it may not be defined (it's an optional value).

If you visit the `ClientUser` documentation, it says it "Represents the logged in client's Discord user."

I'm guessing that if the client has not yet fully logged in, then the `user` property will be undefined. Call `client.login(token)` first, which is an *asynchronous* function, and then you can change the presence.

This means, using promises:

```js
client.login(token).then((token) => {
 // client.user is now defined
 client.user.setPresence({
  game: { name: '.help' },
  status: 'online',
 });
});
```

You may also want to query that `client.user` is defined either way before proceeding to prevent crashing.

I suspect the reason your existing code does not work is because if you do not set the presence in the callback for the login function, you will not yet have finished logging in by the time the rest of the code runs. The following will cause an error:

```js
client.login(token); // bad - this is async
client.user.setPresence(...)
```

Comment: This doesn't give me an error, but also doesn't set the status on the bot.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *quite* an answer, but it's too big to go in a comment. If you want to set the status of the bot right when it goes online, you can define the presence through the `Discord.Client()` constructer itself. One of the [`Client()` constructer's options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) is `presence`.

```js
// at the beginning of your code:
const client = new Discord.Client({
 presence: {
  status: 'online',
  activity: {
   name: '.help',
   type: 'PLAYING',
  },
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.setActivity()` function

```js
client.user.setActivity(".help" {type: "PLAYING"}) //the type can be "PLAYING", "WATCHING", "STREAMING", "LISTENING"
```

Use this in your

```js
client.on('ready' () => {
  client.user.setActivity(".help" {type: "PLAYING"}) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the presence in the `client.on('ready', () => {})` section:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: ".help",
            type: "PLAYING"
        }
    });
});
```

Quick explanation:

The presence is what you are setting, it is made of multiple variables.

The `status` can be `online`, `idle`, `dnd`, or `invisible`. (dnd is Do not disturb)

The other variable here is `activity`. It is a group of two variables: `name` and `type`.

The `name` is what the bot is doing. This is a string of your choice.
The `type` is the other thing that will help it display as. It can be `"PLAYING"`, `"STREAMING"`, `"WATCHING"`, `"LISTENING"`, and `"CUSTOM_STATUS"`.